# SQLite not available with Python 3.3.0 on Debian

Tags: python, sqlite

When i type

```
>>>import sqlite3
```

It pops me the following error

```
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

My setup :

- Debian 6.0.7
- Python installed by default is 2.6.6 (`import sqlite3` works here, version is 3.7.3)
- I've installed Python3.3.0 from [the tarball](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/), and did : `./configure` + `make` + `make install`

From the fresh Python install, i see a directory in `/usr/local/lib/python3.3` named `sqlite3`

I can't say much, its a brand new install, no fancy modules added, just debian + python.

Did you guys faced this error before ? Any idea how to solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python libraries are version specific. You need to separate install sqlite3 for each Python version.

I suggest you create a *virtualenv* isolated Python environment for working your Python 3.3 project and install SQLite under virtualenv using `pip` command:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/